# Not changing Javascript variable value after rerendering

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, rerender

i created a script tag in visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="ActionFunctionDemoController">  
<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="action1" action="{!action1}" rerender="scriptPanel" />

 <apex:outputPanel id="scriptPanel">
 <script>
 var xy="{!xy}";
 console.log(xy);
 setInterval(function(){
 console.log(xy);
 },5000);
 action1();
 </script>
 </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and there is an apex class

```
public with sharing class ActionFunctionDemoController {

    public String xy{get;set;}

    public ActionFunctionDemoController(){

    xy='Hello';
    }

    public Pagereference action1(){
        xy='Hello Hello';
    return null;
    }

}
```

in console every time its give 'Hello' not 'Hello Hello' means script tag is not rerendered.Please guideline how to rerender script tag ??

Comment: Try to put your actionFunction into your outputpanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I test and it works.I am not sure is it return the output that you want.I move the panel to outside of the apex:form.

```
<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction name="action1" action="{!action1}" rerender="scriptPanel" />
</apex:form>
<apex:outputPanel id="scriptPanel">
 <script>
 var xy="{!xy}";
 console.log(xy);
 setInterval(function(){
 console.log(xy);
 },5000);
 action1();
 </script>
 </apex:outputPanel>
```